# RSQL directory of saved database

Tags: database

I am brand new to database creation and trying to learn what they are used for.

Essentially you can create a database and save it to local space instead of memory, and instead query from the local space and load into memory the information desired.

My question is that I am using R and created a database, but where did it save?  how do  I find it?

I checked my working directory to no avail... thank you in advance...

Comment: this saves the database in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

it saves in the working directory.